# Session from javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I'd like to inspect the session variable.  Best case something that works in the firebugs little interpreter, but if I have to put it in the file thats fine.  Right now I just made a short PHP to output $_SESSION, but if I could find something analogous to be done right in the browser that would be ideal.  document.cookie doesn't seem to do what im looking for, at least not that i see.

Basically looking for something analogous to $_SESSION that I can use in javascript

EDIT - was trying to see if i could get anything more than, or extract the meaning  PHPSESSID=o147cf52u9d7qr251hc3n6ilu2; ASESSIONID=101wvpe-3FA77F204CFF55BA61E696AD3F62F0F8 on the client-side.   As it stands I guess i can just write a small ajax function to a url that echos the session.  Thanks for the help!

PS - Do those document.cookie values have anything to do with whats inside the session, or are they just identifiers to tell one session from another?

Comment: You should be able to get something similar to sessions with cookies, can you show us some code, and tell us what it isn't doing that you need?

Comment: nothing the code lacks - was seeing if there was a debug means if seeing this short of ajaxing to such a php file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Session data is stored on the server. It isn't accessible to client-side JavaScript unless you manually expose it (e.g. by writing a PHP program that dumps it to JSON and delivers it over HTTP).

The browser just gets a cookie containing a token that identifiers which packet of session data the server side programs should open for a given client.

Comment: yep thats what i was wondering.  i knew it was stored on server but was wondering if there was some way to get a little more than, or extract meaning from this "PHPSESSID=o147cf52u9d7qr251hc3n6ilu2; ASESSIONID=101wvpe-3FA77F204CFF55BA61E696AD3F62F0F8" i guess if its important enough to me i can write a function to ajax to a small PHP containing little except echo_r($_SESSION)

Answer (score 1):

Just look at what cookies are set in your browser: [Firefox](http://kb.iu.edu/data/ajfi.html),
[Chrome](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95647), etc.

Edit: oooh, after re-reading your question, you want to ACCESS the session data.

That's not possible via JavaScript for ***very*** good reason. XSS would be a breeze. Besides, the data is stored on the server, which JS has no access to (thankfully).

It's not possible to do what you're asking.

Comment: No, this is not what you want.  Cookies do not store session data, usually.  Instead they usually a session ID which identifies session data on the server.  And if they do contain session data they are heavily encrypted in order to make their contents unreadable to anything but the server set that cookie.  Cookies are an important part of sessions, but you cannot ever get session data in javascript without explicitly exposing it.

Comment: @Squeegy i already updated my answer. I had thought the OP just wanted access to the session cookie

Comment: i didnt need full access, was wondering if the cookie could give me something along the lines of its size, number of elements, etc.  I didn't know how "tightly" $_SESSION was held down on the server, or if maybe firebug had some little tricks didnt know

Comment: @jon_darkstar i'm sure you already know, but a simple test script like `<?php var_dump($_SESSION);` can be placed in a separate file to regularly check the status of the session. Then when you're all done, delete the file.

Comment: I use a template engine, MVC framework, etc.  can't just throw tags like that in the file.  was curious how much, if any, of the session was accessible from browser.  even seeing the last time it changed wouldve been helpful

Comment: @jon_darkstar **separate file**: the framework wont matter, just make sure you're using the right session.

Comment: oh gotcha.  the use of the <?php tag threw me off.  I have written something like this, but its in a class, method, etc.  I have a debug PHP file on the server I am constantly changing for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) to debug variables from my Ajax calls, maybe it is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access PHP sessions within JavaScript directly.  You could however make an Ajax call to a PHP script which will return the PHP sessions.  This is your best option.